# How to add Hyperlink-Xaml from code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, richtextbox

I'm having trouble with the following:

```
xaml = @"<Section xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""><Paragraph><Hyperlink Click=""Hyperlink_OnClick"" NavigateUri=""http://www.google.de"">abc</Hyperlink></Paragraph></Section>";

richtext.Xaml = xaml;
```

Removing the whole Hyperlink-Tag makes it work again. Where is the problem here? The whole code works fine, pasting it directly into *.xaml.

I'm getting System.Xml.XmlException' and 'System.ArgumentException' .

Comment: where is `Hyperlink_OnClick` located?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 same cs File like the following: 
`private void Hyperlink_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("asdf");
        }`

Comment: but when you parse the string how does it know where to look, are you able to add more information on what you are trying to do, are you just trying to display the Xaml in the RichTextBox or are you trying to parse it?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I'm not sure whether it gets parsed by simply adding it to the RichTextBox? I'm not doing anything more than the example above. I only generate the xaml string from WebRequest, but pasted the result of my generation here, so it should not matter where the string comes from.
Additionally the errors show up when it tries to execute the assignment (line 2).
I thought it would look up the OnClick like any other directly written xaml...

Comment: Okay, if I remove the onclick, I get it working, but NavigateUri seems not to be enough to open up a link in browser on windows phone. Any way to solve that? (I'd really appreciate getting the OnClick working to track the call and just LaunchUriAsync() ...)